# Is there a command in Vim/Vi to move the cursor to the end of a search highlight?

Tags: vim, vi

Are there any commands in Vim/Vi to move within a selected search segment?

For instance, if I search for a word, are there any commands to motion the cursor to the end of the highlighted segment?  Say I have a word, "FishTaco" and I want to search for all instances of "Fish" and insert something after it.  I know I could do a global replace, but what if I want to only make the change in a couple non-sequential instances?

I could see where it would be convenient to be able to motion the cursor to the end of the current highlighted segment to perform an action.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question, but to achieve your ultimate goal of replacing all `Fish` with `FishTaco`, you could do `:%s/Fish\(Taco\)\@!/&Taco/`, which will find every `Fish` not already followed by `Taco` and replace it with `FishTaco`. Combines a negative-lookahead search with a replace that includes the matched term followed by `Taco`.

Comment: @JimStewart I have no idea why this comment doesn't have at least as many +1's as the answer. This is ninja level vim.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

You can do it with this:

`/Fish/e`

The `/e` at the end lands your cursor at the end of the search region (instead of the first character by default.

Comment: Note that you can add *+n* or *-n* to put the cursor *n* characters before or after the end.

Comment: Worth noting that after you've already done the `/Fish` search you can jump to the end with `//e` and from Vim 7.4 you can use `gn` to visually highlight the found result.

Comment: Take a look at [@ghbarratt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10707850/3550735) answer too, more options to locate cursor on highlighted match.

Comment: This only works if all meta characters are properly escaped.`/[/e`  will literally search for `[/e`, but `/\[/e` will properly search for `[` and place cursor at end :)

Answer (score 96):

If you just want to place your cursor after the last character of Fish then you could use

```
/Fish/e+1
```

which will place your cursor after the h. (Without the `+1` the cursor will end up to the left of the last character.)

If you are particularly interested in placing the cursor after Fish, but only when it appears in "FishTaco" then you can try one of the following options:

You can use

```
/FishTaco/s+4
```

and your cursor will end up between Fish and Taco. The `/s+4` places the cursor 4 places after the start of the search term.

You could likewise use

```
/FishTaco/e-3
```

which will place your cursor 3 places left of the left side of the last (end) character.

You can also use

```
/FishTaco/b+4
```

because `/b+4` will be treated as `/s+4`.

Comment: Great explanation, but now I'm just hungry.

Answer (score 30):

If you have already searched for `/Fish`, you can quickly change the search to go to the end of the match via `//e`, which repeats the last search, but appends the `e` modifier that has already been explained.

Comment: the //e+number is exactly what I was looking for! awesome.

Answer (score 15):

`/ long-regexp1 \zs long-regexp2 /`    *.. cursor will stop at \zs*, see :help \zs

Answer (score 13):

Once you have a visual selection, you can use `o` to toggle the cursor position between the start and end of the selected block. When the selection is line-wise this toggles the *line* position, meaning the cursor moves to the starting and ending line of the selection but not to the starting or ending character. When the selection is character-wise then the movement is also character-wise.

You can also use `` `< `` and `` `> `` to toggle the cursor between the start and end of the visual block, however this affects the selection itself, so it is used to reset or adjust the selection bounds.

Edit: Ah, but for search highlights this won't work, because `o` will initiate a line insertion. I guess search highlight isn't the same as a visual selection, sorry :)

Comment: I didn't know that either. This is great to modify the beginning of a selection without starting over. (e.g. you started the selection one word too soon or too late)

Comment: Search isn't a visual selection because you can use both together. While you're establishing a visual selection, you can use `/` and `?` search to move around.

Answer (score 9):

The "cursor at the end of the match" part of your question is already answered.

You can do `:%s/Fish/FishTaco/c`. This gives you an opportunity to confirm or reject every substitution and skip the whole "cursor at the end of the match" business.

Comment: Awesome tip.  If I enter 'y' it only performs the replacement on the first.  How do I make it confirm for each one?

Comment: It goes to the next match and waits for you to type `y` or `n` and so on until there are no matches left. To accept all further substitutions, type `a`, to reject them, type `q`.

Comment: Actually, I was missing the `g` after the final `/` so it wasn't continuing in my line.  Thanks for the tip.